# named scope syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have the following model object: `Issue.owner = [array]`

I'm trying to create a scope, where scope searches the array for a specific integer, such as this:

```
scope :tagged_in_issue, where("issues.owner.include?(1)", true)
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Do you want the owner field to have "1" anywhere in it or be just "1" ? 
Is owner a Ruby related field (owner_id) or a simple integer field (owner)?

scope :tagged_in_issue, where("issues.owner= ?", 1)

Comment: Look at the section "Cross Model Scopes" here: http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html . What you really want to do is make a JOIN like that.

Comment: What is this scope defined in?

What does one of the values in the owner column of the issues table look like?

If it's a serialized ruby array of integers you'll need a certain query, if you've got a join model in between then you'll need a different query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add method like this:

```
class Issue < AR::Base
  def tagged_in_issue?(n)
    owner.include?(n)
  end
end

@issue.tagged_in_issue(1)
#=> true
@issue.tagged_in_issue(2)
#=> false
```

**UPD**

As far as you need `scope` my approach is not something you need. So you can do it this way (Ruby way)

```
class Issue < AR::Base
  def self.tagged_in_issue(n)
    all.select{|a| a.owner.include?(n)}
  end
end

Issue.tagged_in_issue(1)
#=> Array of issues
```

If you want to do it through SQL, so you should describe what `owner` attribute is and where does it store

Comment: Depending on how many Issues you are going to have, it could be grossly inefficient to dump the entire database like that and loop through all of them.

Comment: @scragz, +1, but JZ didn't give us information about `owner` nature

Comment: Calling `all` and then `select` is going to be murder on any application with a non-trivial number of records.

Comment: it is only solution with data we have :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Ruby where it's expecting SQL. The parameter to the `where` clause should be something that it can use in SQL such as a literal string, an array with placeholders, or a hash with column-value pairs.

What you have to do is re-phrase your query as a SQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: well I'm in trouble. haha. How do you search an array in SQL then for the integer 1?

Comment: What do you mean array? SQL really doesn't have those. It does have result sets. Maybe what you want is `issues.where(:owner_id => 1)` but this won't work if you're using a `serialize` column since that's stored in a format that SQL doesn't understand.